# Jquery append() method and chaining order debug

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to insert a new row into a table with Jquery. Can someone comment between the two techniques:

1. This works correctly:

   ```
   $('<tr>').append(row).appendTo(table);
   ```
2. This does not work, but it is not clear why?

   ```
   $(row).appendTo($('<tr>')).appendTo(table);
   ```

Answer (score 6):

```
$(row).appendTo($('<tr>').appendTo(table));
```

Try that. It looks like you just placed your parentheses in the wrong order.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm pretty new to JS and Jquery.. However, you should check John's post below.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(row).appendTo($('<tr>'))
```

This adds row to a newly created `<tr>`. This returns a jQuery reference to `row` - **NOT** to the newly created `<tr>`

```
                          .appendTo(table);
```

Adds `row` to `table`, thus removing it from the newly created `<tr>`.

Try this instead. It gets the references straight.

```
$('<tr>').append(row).appendTo(table);
```

Comment: Your last code block was #1 in the question, but to me that is not very elegant.

Comment: As I say above:  You're appending row a dynamic tr, then immediately appending it (row) to the table.  : )

Comment: @Casey so it is :) i didnt look back up at your question after writing that part.

Comment: @John not true. I am appending `row` to a dynamic row and then adding the `tr` to the table. `append` does not change the chain. It returns the `tr`.

Comment: @Casey per being elegant, i dont have a problem with it. i can read it fine. i suppose it comes down to a matter of personal style.

Comment: @Jeff - You know... you're totally right.  Sorry about that.  : )

Comment: @John no problem. no one is on 100% of the time :)

Answer (score 1):

Your scope is off.  appendTo will not change the scope of the chain.  You're appending row a dynamic tr, then immediately appending it to the table.

---

Snowblind's solution will work, this will work:  $`(table).append($(row).wrap('<tr></tr>'));`

There are probably a bunch of other derivations.  Just make sure you take a bit of chain understanding from this.  : )

Comment: i wasn't able to work out the wrap example. I tried: table.append($('<td>1</td>').wrap('<tr></tr>'));

Answer (score 1):

In your second example...

```
$(row).appendTo($('<tr>')).appendTo(table);
```

The set when you call `appendTo()` the second time is not what you think it is. It will be `row`.

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/6SUFb/) should make it clearer.